# Importing module not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, module

I have a django (but i think it's nor revelant here) project where I try to add a script i did before. So I put it in a subdirectory of my project, and i have this structure (I know it's a little bit of a mess at the moment but it won't stay exactly like that)

[image]

From **views.py** i want to import **main.py** (Especially the function **excelToXml**) . After searches on internet i found that code that i copied in views.py . If I undestood it right it add to the variable $PATH the directory parent of **first_page** and though, every subdirectory

```
CURRENT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PARENT = os.path.dirname(CURRENT)
sys.path.append(PARENT)
from ExcelToXML.main import excelToXml
```

I also created a file **__init.py_**_ in the directory ExcelToXML, this file is left empty.

However even I did all that i still get this error when i run the django server

> File "c:\Users\CRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\DevisVersOpen\DevisVersOpen\urls.py", line 18, in module
>
> > from first_page import views
>
> File
>   "c:\Users\CRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\DevisVersOpen\first_page\views.py",
>   line 13, in module
>
> > from ExcelToXML.main import excelToXml
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ExcelToXML'

I didn't find any solution that I could understand on internet so I really don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your directory structure let me think that you should try to import like this :

```
from first_page.ExcelToXML.main import excelToXml
```

because the ExcelToXML is under the first_page module, so it is viewed as a submodule of first_page.

Answer (score 3):

Check this for details on what is **init**.py file [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

The **init**.py file should be present in every directory and sub directories whose classes should be made visible for import. In your case, the I am suspecting that the parent directory does not have the **init**.py file. Add the file in the parent directory and import it as follows

import first_page.ExcelToXML

Answer (score 0):

Okay hello, the solution you found is (I think) a mess, you should read the official documentation about it https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#packages. 
In short just add `from .idea.main import excelToXml`.
If it does not work, rename `.idea` folder to `idea`(without the dot) and add in your `views.py` this line :`from idea.main import excelToXml`

Answer (score 0):

For python change the location of the import file and then import. It worked for me.
Location can be: `C:\python 3.8\Lib`